# Angular -> No template for dependency: ConstDependency

Tags: angular, npm, dependencies, web-worker

Here is my code:

```
const worker = new Worker('./app.worker.ts', { type: 'module' });
console.log('this is the worker');
console.log(worker);
worker.onmessage = ({ data }) => {
  console.log(`page got message: ${data}`);
};
worker.postMessage('hello');
```

It is having trouble on that first line. If I remove the {type: 'module'} it does not give me the error (but it also does not work). I have tried npm prune and npm dedupe but that did not fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Removing `webpack` packages from `package.json` didn't resolve this for me.

Running `npm i worker-plugin --save-dev` resolved it for me. When running `ng g web-worker` the Angular CLI doesn't install the package.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue recently and `npm prune` or `npm dedupe` didn't work. I managed to fix the issue by removing webpack packages from `package.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

As for me, something was wrong with my `package.json`.
The error was as follows.

```
No template for dependency: ModuleHotAcceptDependency
```

I missed `cross-env` before `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=true` with two entries.

```
- "start": "cross-env REACT_APP_VERSION=$npm_package_version; cross-env BUILD_DEV=true cross-env REACT_APP_BUILD_DEV=true GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=true node scripts/start.js",
- "build:dev": "cross-env REACT_APP_VERSION=$npm_package_version; cross-env BUILD_DEV=true cross-env REACT_APP_BUILD_DEV=true GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=true node scripts/build.js",
+ "start": "cross-env REACT_APP_VERSION=$npm_package_version; cross-env BUILD_DEV=true cross-env REACT_APP_BUILD_DEV=true cross-env GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=true node scripts/start.js",
+ "build:dev": "cross-env REACT_APP_VERSION=$npm_package_version; cross-env BUILD_DEV=true cross-env REACT_APP_BUILD_DEV=true cross-env GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=true node scripts/build.js",
```

Only when `start` and `build:dev` both missed `cross-env` will lead to the issue. Eihter missed was ok. I guess it may trigger a parsing issue.